# ASP.Net, How to solve this error

Tags: asp.net

### `Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 29:    </connectionStrings>
Line 30:    <system.web>
**Line 31:      <sessionState timeout="20"></sessionState>**
Line 32:        <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
Line 33:        <!--
```

Source File: D:\SILINDIA\WEBSITE\web.config    Line: 31

Comment: If the /website/ is the root of the site then you do not have setup it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The exception itself contains a solution:

> This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured
>   as an application in IIS.

From IIS make this virtual directory a web application, following are the step of creating a web application: [Create a Web Application](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772042%28WS.10%29.aspx)